# How to successfully create tags that link to posts using the Gatsby starter blog?

Tags: gatsby

I've been trying to add a tags page on the gatsby starter blog to no prevail. I followed the tutorial in the docs and successfully got a list of tags from markdown posts, however the links through a 404.
And there was several errors on dev.
Maybe due to the tutorial being outdated perhaps.
Is there an example of a gatsby-starter-blog using links?

I've reverted gatsby-node-js file back to default now.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to create a page for each tag that shows an index of all of the posts that belong to the tag?

Comment: Yes exactly, and when you click on the post name in the index, it takes you to that specific post. So a visitor could see a list of categories/tags, see all posts within the category/tag name and click on the post they want to read.

Comment: Have you gone through the tutorial? https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-seven/

Comment: Yes I have gone through that tutorial. Perfectly fine. This is the tutorial on the docs for creating tags pages. https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-tags-and-categories-to-blog-posts/ I have followed this however I encountered lots of errors. Managed to get a list of tags however on clicking the links the site crashed. Started with the gatsby-starter-blog.

Comment: Do you want to add your code, and an example of the errors you are seeing to your question? It would make it easier for someone to try to help you.

Comment: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog Link to the starter I'm using. I no longer have errors due to revering back to this basic starter.